# Need help converting SQL query to Ruby.

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console, enumerator

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to determine the proper ruby query for the following SQL query.

Select max(bid_amount) from biddings where listing_id = 1;

I need to extract the maximum value in the bid_amount column. But it has to have a dynamic listing_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Bidding.where('listing_id = :listing_id', listing_id: 1).maximum(:bid_amount)
```

**Update:**

To follow up on your comment: since you say you are passing in `params[:id]`, it's best to convert that parameter to integer so that unwanted values don't go to the database.  For e.g.

```
Bidding.where('listing_id = :listing_id', listing_id: params[:id].to_i).maximum(:bid_amount)
```

Comment: It worked! I had to add params[:id] to capture correct listing_id from the route.

Comment: @RajveerSinghTut, yes you would know what to pass in.  But one extra suggestion is if you're passing `params[:id]` then it's better to convert that value to integer, i.e. `params[:id].to_i`

Comment: Why is it better to convert that value to an integer?

Comment: @RajveerSinghTut, in the answer I've provided you don't really need to worry about it.  I'm not sure if you're aware of this already but I think it will be beneficial to read:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection.